# Remove an alias on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, alias

I've set an alias for a command and now I want to remove it again. How would I go about that? I've already tried `unalias`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What happens exactly when you used the unalias command?

Comment: @EBgreen what does a command have to do with a command prompt command?

Comment: Never mind...I see, an Alias for a **command**. Disregard.

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't find the command.

Comment: Just to clrify Kyr, is this in the command prompt or powershell. What command exactly did you use to create the alias?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about PowerShell:

`remove-item alias:\<alias name>`

So if you made an Alias named "MyAlias", you'd remove it with `remove-item alias:\MyAlias`.

More info: [Using the Set-Alias Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176958.aspx)

Comment: thing is, powershell informs me that the drive alias:/ wasn't found

Comment: Uhh that's weird.  As EBGreen asked, what was the EXACT command you used to create the alias, and what's the exact removal command you tried to use that told you the drive didn't exist?